# how to transform an object to an array based on key/value?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with few properties true/false, I need to return an array with only the property name with true.

I have tried Object.entries but not sure how to create an array now.

```
const inputs = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false
}


// result should be ['a','b']

// i have tried so far this one with no success
// const result = Object.entries(inputs).map((x, idx) => console.log(x))
```

Comment: Try `Object.keys(inputs).filter(key => inputs[key]);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Object.keys(inputs).filter(key => inputs[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use my JSFiddle for the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/404_Error/kymgoz5d/)

Use the [filter array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), described by MDN as

> creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function

Call it on the Object.keys, a built in array for objects:

> returns an array of a given object's property names

Source: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

So, to put it together, it would look like

```
const inputs = {
 a: true,
 b: true,
 c: false
}
console.log(inputs); // Output: {a: true, b: true, c: false}

const arr = Object.keys(inputs).filter(keyName => inputs[keyName]);
console.log(arr); // Output: ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For give only keys of object use `filter`:

Like this:

```js
const inputs = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false
};

var true_inputs = Object.keys(inputs).filter(key => inputs[key]);
console.log(true_inputs);
```

Or Jquery `map`:

```js
const inputs = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false
};


var true_inputs = $.map(inputs, function(n, i) { if(n) return i });
console.log(true_inputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For to get the whole object use `for .. in`:
Like this:

```js
const inputs = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false
};


var true_inputs = {};

for(var key in inputs){
 if(inputs[key])
   true_inputs[key]=inputs[key];
}

console.log(inputs);
console.log(true_inputs);
```